# How do I get rid of error 3014?

Tags: diablo-iii

While I'm still on the fence about supporting Diablo 3 with my money, I have no problem supporting it with my brother's money. Since he's away from his machine quite a bit, he told me to give the game a spin on his account.

Since I wanted to avoid downloading the game, I decided I'd fire up the beta client, assuming it would let me know if it's no longer usable or that it would maybe auto-update.

The client claimed to be good to go, but when I tried to log in I got treated to a dialog box that told me "An error has occurred". This informative error was numbered 3014.

Looking around the web, I see that some people claim this error is directly tied to using the beta client, while others claim they are getting this with the most up-to-date client.

So does anyone know what this error actually means? Will dumping the beta client for the new one actually help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been explicitly communicated by Blizzard to remove the Beta before installing the official Diablo 3 release. As I first attempt to solve your problem I would try to get rid of beta client by uninstalling it.

Comment: Funny how such a thing gets pushed out of the way by people wondering what the error is when performing a search. Thanks.